# rust-analyzer inlay hints mostly works, but I get the elipsis (...) for types of variables. How do I get the full type for variable declarations?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, rust-analyzer, inlay-hints

I'm just a beginner to Rust, but got rustup, cargo, rustc etc all working and VSCode set up. Even breakpoints work. For function parameters I *sometimes* get the proper type hints, but for variable declarations I only see ...

I wonder why I see no inlay hint for `String::from("Hallo ");` but do get an inlay hint for `greetings.push_str("Richard");`?
The only difference I see is that the first call is to a static function, while the 2nd is to an object method.

Settings:

```
"rust-analyzer.inlayHints.bindingModeHints.enable": true,
"rust-analyzer.inlayHints.closingBraceHints.enable": false,
"rust-analyzer.inlayHints.closingBraceHints.minLines": 10,
"rust-analyzer.inlayHints.closureReturnTypeHints.enable": "always",
"rust-analyzer.inlayHints.expressionAdjustmentHints.enable": "always",
"rust-analyzer.inlayHints.expressionAdjustmentHints.hideOutsideUnsafe": true,
"rust-analyzer.inlayHints.lifetimeElisionHints.enable": "always",
"rust-analyzer.inlayHints.lifetimeElisionHints.useParameterNames": true,
"rust-analyzer.inlayHints.maxLength": 0,
"rust-analyzer.inlayHints.reborrowHints.enable": "always",
//"rust-analyzer.inlayHints.typeHints.hideNamedConstructor": true,
"rust-analyzer.inlayHints.typeHints.enable": true,
"rust-analyzer.checkOnSave.command":"clippy",
"rust-analyzer.displayInlayHints":true,
```

Then question 2 (perhaps this should be a separate question): why can't I factor out rust-analyzer.inlayHints and write something like this in the settings?

```
   "rust-analyzer" :  {
        "inlayHints" : {
            "closingBraceHints.minLines": 10,
            "maxLength": 0,
            "expressionAdjustmentHints.enable": "always",
            "lifetimeElisionHints.enable": "never",
            "reborrowHints.enable": "always",
        },
        "checkOnSave.command":"clippy",
        "displayInlayHints":true
    },
```

[image]

Comment: Can the person who voted to close add a comment why?

Comment: Please ask in superuser. Not a programming-question.

Comment: @kometen Questions about "software tools commonly used by programmers" are [on-topic for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), I think VSCode and rust-analyzer qualify.

Answer (score 1):

You set inlay hints' `maxLength` to zero. Set it to something higher and you will see the types.

Comment: Thanks a lot. And you were fast, too.  I read somewhere that setting this to 0 meant unlimited length...

It would be great if I could factor out / group settings like the example above, to me these are semantically equivalent. But by grouping I reduce redundancy and everything is grouped. If I edit the settings with the GUI, all rust-analyzer settings can get spread all over the place.
"rust-analyzer" :  {
        "inlayHints" : {